# Using dynamic Linq (System.Linq.Dynamic) to create an array of values instead of a sum of values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, lambda, extension-methods

I'm using the class called System.Linq.Dynamic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb894665.aspx). It is used to define dynamic Linq queries. I need my queries to be dynamic so they can be defined at runtime.

I have transaction data stored in an object called **trans**. The data is very simple with 4 fields: AccountNumber (string) and Value (decimal).

I'm doing a query like so:

```
var dynamic = trans.AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy("new(AccountNumber)", "it")
    .Select(@"new(  Key.AccountNumber as groupId,
                    Sum(Value) as groupTotal,
                    it as data)");
```

This works wonders and gives me a result that is structured like the following:

```
[
    {
        "groupId": 15,
        "groupTotal": 5912.52,
        "data": [
            {
                "AccountNumber": 15,
                "Value": 14.25
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

**What I want to do is something like this:**

```
var dynamic = trans.AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy("new(AccountNumber)", "it")
    .Select(@"new(  Key.AccountNumber as groupId,
                    ToArray(Value) as groupList,
                    it as data)");
```

**Which would ultimately give me a result that looked like the following:**

```
[
    {
        "groupId": 15,
        "groupList": [14.25, 300.23, 63.88, 2767.08, 1383.54, 1000.54, 383.00],
        "data": [
            {
                "AccountNumber": 15,
                "Value": 14.25
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

**How do I go about modifying Dynamic.cs so that it can support such a thing?**

Please note, the differences between the two queries are **Sum(Value) as groupTotal,** and  **ToArray(Value) as groupList,** where the Sum will work but currently the ToArray will not.

I do know that I will require some extension methods or similar in order to accomplish this task. Unfortunately, my skills with Linq, Lambda and extension methods are at a beginners level.

Comment: Why not just `Value`?

Comment: Because I'm grouping by AccountNumber, Value is not available. I have already tried this. Unless you mean something different. If I do something like var dynamic = trans.AsQueryable() .GroupBy("new(AccountNumber)", "Value") .Select(@"new( Key.AccountNumber as groupId, it as groupList)"); then yes, I get an array of Values but I also require the rest of the data at included in each group, which is why I use "it".

Comment: What happens when you try replacing "ToArray(Value)" with "Value" or "Value.ToArray()" ?